# MySQL combining multiple columns with GROUP_CONCAT, per row

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have some objects which have duplicates. One table stores the objects (the 'primaries'); another stores the one-to-many relation of objects to their duplicates (the 'secondaries'):

```
Objects
-------
`obj`
A1
A1a
A1b
A2
```

```
Duplicates
----------
`primary`,`secondary`
A1, A1a
A1, A1b
```

I'm trying to devise a single query that uses GROUP_CONCAT to return a summary of objects and their duplicates, returning one row per object: [`obj`, `primary`, combined `secondary` columns], like:

```
 A1,   A1,(A1a,A1b)
 A1a,  A1,(A1a,A1b)
 A1b,  A1,(A1a,A1b)
 A2,   NULL
```

Trying to do

```
SELECT `obj`, `primary`, GROUP_CONCAT(`secondary`) 
FROM `Objects`
LEFT JOIN `Duplicates` on (`obj`=`primary` OR `obj`=`secondary`)
```

is returning only a single row, containing a concat of all secondaries from all rows:

```
 a1a,a1a,  a1b,a1b,a1c,a1c,a2b,a2b
```

Thanks for any help!

@PM 77-1 (thanks) suggested adding a GROUP BY clause. I tried this:

```
SELECT `obj`, `primary`, GROUP_CONCAT(`secondary`) 
FROM `Objects`
LEFT JOIN `Duplicates` on (`obj`=`primary` OR `obj`=`secondary`) GROUP BY `obj`
```

which improved things, and gives 4 rows, one for each instance of `obj`, and the results are what I want for A1 and A2, but each of obj A1a and A1b should be A1a,A1b.

```
obj primary GROUP_CONCAT(`secondary`)
A1  A1      A1a,A1b
A1a A1      A1a
A1b A1      A1b
A2  NULL    NULL
```

[BTW I forgot that primary is a reserved word so in my test implementation this is actually `primaryy`!]

So, still stuck on this...

Edit:

I'm not stuck anymore! The result above is what I wanted! Thanks to @PM 77-1.

Comment: Consider adding a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you @PM 77-1, I've tried this and updated my original post.

Comment: You seem to be treating your `primary` and `secondary` designation interchangeably.  Can you [edit] your question and explain the exact logic behind your results for `obj` values of `A1a` and `A1b`?

Comment: Seems odd that both a primary and secondary  have the same expected results `A1,(A1a,A1b)`

Comment: Thnaks to @PM77-1